# JLabel does not align correctly with GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, grid-layout

The label does not align to the left of the center layout. If the `GridLayout` is not present, then it moves correctly. Is there a way to do it to move JLabel to the extreme left?

I've tried setHorizontalAlignment and setAlignmentX and both did not work

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class asd {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("LABEL",SwingConstants.LEFT);
        //lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3,2,1);
        JPanel yourGrid = new JPanel(grid);
        panel.add(lab);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                JButton but = new JButton();
                yourGrid.add(but);
            }
        }
        panel.add(yourGrid);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using BoxLayout you have to set the alignment for any of the elements inside.

As this example follows:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

**Fixing Alignment Problems**

You have to set alignment to your lab and yourGrid

```
lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
yourGrid.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

Comment: yourGrid.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); is illegal.

Comment: solved, I dont have a compiler in front to test the code atm, ty! :D

Comment: One more thing! What if there are two `JLabel`s and I need to place one to the extreme left and the other to the extreme right. How should the `JPanel` be aligned?

Comment: `setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);` and then `add(label1); add(Box.createHoritzonalGlue());add(label2);`